# What hook for updating product in WooCommerce Dokan plugin from vendor panel?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, dokan

I want to do some customization in dokan plugin. I want to know if there is a hook available for update product from vendor panel.

Answer (score 4):

After adding the input filed you have to save the value of the field. On that place you have to use `do_action( 'dokan_new_product_added', $product_id, $post_data );` this hook to save the field data.

When you will edit the product that time you have to use `do_action( 'dokan_product_updated', $post_id );` to re-save.